# Shorter null check

Tags: c#

Can I shorten something like this

```
if (variable != null) 
{
   Function();
}
```

to something like this

```
variable? Function();
```

but that actually works ?

Comment: No, you cannot.

Comment: @canton7 you can post this as answer

Comment: @Cid Honestly? I don´t find this question - nor the answer - any useful to anyone.

Comment: You could one-line it as `if (variable != null) Function()` if you really wanted... This is the sort of answer that gets downvoted though (and with good reason), so I don't feel inclined to post it

Comment: I upvoted - this site is too harsh on beginners. We all had to start somewhere.

Comment: Hi ZigiZen and welcome to StackOverflow. Please consider expanding myour question into something that is not a pure yes/no-question. For example, add WHY you are looking for an expression comprehension, so that others may give you suggestions on the best way to solve your problem.

Comment: If you want to call a function only if a variable has value, then most likely tath function uses that variable. If is that the case, you could declare the function `private void Function(MyVariableType variable)` and do the null check inside the function `if (variable == null) return;`

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't.

But if `Function()` is a member of `variable` you can use the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) for the same effect:

```
variable?.Function();
```